# Constrains using DATE

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, check-constraints

I'm trying to create a constrain to check the record is no greater than 2016.

Here is the record in my database

[image]

Here is my query:

```
ALTER TABLE SIGHTINGS 
   ADD CONSTRAINT CK_SIGHTING_DATE 
   CHECK (SIGHTING_DATE <=TO_DATE('01-JAN-16'));
```

But I got an error says: ERROR at line 1:

> ORA-02436: date or system variable wrongly specified in CHECK
>   constraint.

I've checked some similar questions on this website but there solutions doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use the `extract()` function as you just want to check for the year:

```
ALTER TABLE SIGHTINGS 
   ADD CONSTRAINT CK_SIGHTING_DATE 
   CHECK (extract(year from SIGHTING_DATE) < 2016);
```

or use an ANSI date literal:

```
ALTER TABLE SIGHTINGS 
   ADD CONSTRAINT CK_SIGHTING_DATE 
   CHECK (SIGHTING_DATE < date '2016-01-01');
```

Comment: I've tried both options, but I get this error: ORA-02293: cannot validate (S4369490.CK_SIGHTING_DATE) - check constraint
violated.

Comment: @SeanLi: then apparently you are inserting rows that violate that rule (e.g. a date that is in 2016)

Comment: Do you mean there are already some existing records violate that rule?

Answer (score 0):

you have make in date specifcation

```
ALTER TABLE SIGHTINGS 
   ADD CONSTRAINT CK_SIGHTING_DATE 
   CHECK (SIGHTING_DATE <= 
               /*TO_DATE('01-JAN-16','DD-MON-YY') as I was pointed your should specify 4 digits for year*/ 
                 TO_DATE('01-JAN-2016','DD-MON-YYYY'));
```

or

```
 ALTER TABLE SIGHTINGS 
   ADD CONSTRAINT CK_SIGHTING_DATE 
   CHECK (SIGHTING_DATE <=DATE'2016-01-01');
```

another one things its what do you mean when you say "no greater than 2016"
Your check alow dates in 01-jan-2016 but not allow 02-jan-2016. 
If you would like to include whole 2016 year write

```
SIGHTING_DATE < DATE'2017-01-01'
```

or 
    trunc(SIGHTING_DATE,'yy') <=DATE'2016-01-01'

Comment: `'01-JAN-16','DD-MON-YY'` depends on local NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE, it may fail for other languages than english. Also two digit year `16` is not very smart.

Comment: How it depend? I write a chacter string and specify a format. In whole century from 2000 to 2099 it will return date 01 january 2016.

Comment: When I try your first proposal I get the same error: **ORA-02436: date or system variable wrongly specified in CHECK constraint**